# NGinx to Apache SSL Proxy - Exposing weakness using VPS?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssl

There are several questions and how-tos, on how to setup NGinx to work with Apache in handling SSL requests, but after reading several of them, I noticed a pattern, which raised the following question, one I would like a concrete answer to, whilst still in the design phase.

Each of the aforementioned articles and how-tos say it's ok to establish a default (non-secure) connection to an server via port 80 within an internal network from the NGinx server. But if the connection between the user and NGinx is meant to be secure, doesn't this non-ssl approach from NGinx to another server expose a weakness in the connection? For example, I use linode VPS and they have several data centers where I can spin up a VPS. So if I have my nginx server acting as a load balancer in Dallas (central to US), then have edge node VPS in CA and NY, wouldn't the connection from NGinx to either of these VPS be susceptible to packet sniffing, as it is not encrypted?

It seems to me, the ideal setup would be to establish another ssl connection from the NGinx server to whichever edge node vps server will handle the request, thereby ensuring a truly secure connection from browser to edge node.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Only if you host in a colocated rack where physical access to servers is controlled and/or restricted, you could give up that extra cryptographed connection between your front and back ends.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. If the edge node has an internal ip address and is not accessible via static ip address, then it should be fine, but in the above example, it would be good practice to ensure a truly point-to point-to point ssl connection?

Comment: Yes, if you are crazy about security and you hosting provider do not have any clauses about information security enforcing, and at the expense of extra CPU usage, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it really helps. If you want to respond to this question with an answer, I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you're paranoid about the security and your hosting provider do not ensure information security for their clients (you), and If you do not have colocated rack with controlled and/or restricted access, you should encrypt the connection between load balancer and back end at the expense of extra CPU usage.

Comment: Thanks again, wanted to validate my question before moving on. Hopefully this will help someone down the road.